# qmake "system" command always return success code

Tags: windows, qt, build, qt5, qmake

I am writing the auto-build system for the one complicated Qt5 program.
Some of it's C++ sources contains special markers and need to be processed by the external utility.
So i decide to write a custom prebuild step in qmake project like this:

```
!build_pass {
    win32 {
         for( src, SOURCES ) {
            system("findstr \"MY_CUSTOM_MARKER\" $$src"):system( MyExternalUtil $$src )
         }
     }
}
```

But first `system` command *always* return success, i.e. all of my sources will be processed!
However, [official Qt documentation say they should not](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#system-command).

So my question is: why such `system` command always returns `0`?

*P.S. I tried it in the Windows command prompt: `findstr` properly set `%errorlevel%` to the `1` when specified text was not found.*

*P.P.S Here is the workaround(just use other version of `system`):*

```
!build_pass {
    win32 { 
         for( SRC_PATH, SOURCES ) {
             FULL_SRC_PATH = \"$$PWD/$$SRC_PATH\"
             FULL_SRC_PATH = $$replace( FULL_SRC_PATH, /, \ )

             FIND_RES = $$system( findstr \"MY_CUSTOM_MARKER\" $$FULL_SRC_PATH )
             !isEmpty( FIND_RES ) {
                 message( Processing $$SRC_PATH... )
                 system( MyExternalUtil $$FULL_SRC_PATH )
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
defineTest(systemWrapper) {
    ret = $$system($${ARGS} 2> /dev/null; echo $?)
    equals(ret, 0):return(true)
    return(false)
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.